# React-Native text gets vertically cut off for no reason

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an interesting bug that is happening to my text. For some reason text is randomly getting cut off like so:

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    width:"100%",
    paddingTop:"5%"
  },
  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    margin:"5%",
    marginTop: 0,
    borderRadius:5,
    width: "90%"
  },
  itemHeaderContainer: {
    padding:15,
    borderColor: "#E4E2E9",
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  },
  itemHeaderText: {
    height:'auto',
    color:"#333",
    fontSize: 23,
    fontWeight: "800",
  },
  itemButtonContainer: {padding:13, flexWrap: 'wrap',  alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection:'row'},
  itemButtonText: { fontSize:19, color:"#fff", fontWeight:"800" },
  itemCreateButton: { backgroundColor:"#3F61E7", borderRadius: 5, paddingVertical:10, paddingHorizontal:15},
});

renderTemplate() {
  if(this.state.loaded) {
    return (
      <View style={{width:"100%"}}>

      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={[styles.itemHeaderContainer, {borderBottomWidth: 0}]}>
          <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{this.state.task_data.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{ marginTop:10, fontSize:18, color:"#333", fontWeight:"400" }}>Line 1</Text> 
          <Text style={{ marginTop:10, fontSize:18, color:"#333", fontWeight:"400" }}>Line 2</Text>
          <Text style={{ marginTop:10, fontSize:18, color:"#333", fontWeight:"400" }}>Line 3</Text> 
          <Text style={{ marginTop:10, fontSize:18, color:"#333", fontWeight:"400" }}>Line 4</Text> 
          <Text style={{ marginTop:10, fontSize:18, color:"#333", fontWeight:"400" }}>Line 5</Text> 
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={[styles.itemContainer, {padding:15}]}>
        <Text style={[styles.itemHeaderText, {}]}>Cut off Text????</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.itemHeaderContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Another Section</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.itemButtonContainer}>
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#3F61E7' style={[styles.itemCreateButton, {marginRight: 10}]}>
              <View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap',  alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.itemButtonText}>Button 1</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>

             <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#3F61E7' style={styles.itemCreateButton}>
              <View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap',  alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.itemButtonText}>Button 2</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.itemHeaderContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Existing Documents</Text>
        </View>
        
        <FlatList data={this.state.task_documents} style={{ paddingBottom:10, paddingHorizontal:0 }} renderItem={
          ({item}) => (

            <View style={{ borderBottomWidth:1, borderColor:"#F1F0F3"}}>
              <View style={[{flexGrow:1, paddingHorizontal:5, flex:1, }]}>
                <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail' style={{ flexShrink: 1, fontSize:24, fontWeight:"600",}}>{item.value.title || "No Title"}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )
        } />
      </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
  else return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <View style={[styles.itemHeaderContainer, {borderBottomWidth: 0}]}>
        <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Loading item..</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderTemplate()}          
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Interestingly enough, the more Lines I put under Testing Task, the more it gets cut off.

- If I move everything from `renderTemplate()` to `render()`, it doesn't get cut off
- If I remove the lines entirely, the text doesn't get cut off.
- If I replace FlatList return to null or remove it, it doesn't get cut off.
- Basically when I start doing random removals of content, things start affect other elements in weird ways.

Has this ever happened to anyone else? Am I doing something wrong? Open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: My first guess would be that it has to do with "flex" and that element being shrunk. Have you tried adding "flex-shrink: 0" to the View around that text?

Comment: you should add some padding to the view

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
<View style={[styles.itemContainer, { padding: 15 }]}>
  <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Cut off Text????</Text>
</View>
```

The padding should be applied to the `Text` component instead of the `View` container:

```
<View style={styles.itemContainer}>
  <Text style={[styles.itemHeaderText, { padding: 15 }]}>Cut off Text????</Text>
</View>
```

Working code: https://snack.expo.io/Hkn9YIC17

Comment: Very interesting, nice catch! Do you know why this would be the case? Is it normally bad practice to add padding to a `View`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with having padding on View. The problem is caused by having a percentage value as the margin, which compresses the view. Changing the margin from `5%` to `Dimensions.get('window').width / 20` would fix it too. Though adding padding to the inner text component makes more sense here too.

Answer (score 5):

You can just add the line-height for the text, here you have the fontSize of 23, then you should be using the line-height of 27 or 28, basically the line height should be 4-5 pixel more than that of your text, that works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

As @riwu stated, this issue is caused by having a percentage value as the margin, which compresses the view. I was curious exactly what this meant, so I looked into it.

It is currently a known issue that currently has not been addressed. This [first issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19164) created for it was closed, but there is [another issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18911) currently open. Using a margin will alter the view, messing up your other styles. A workaround that I found useful was declaring a global value for percentage. I am using react-native-extended-stylesheets and this looks like:

```js
ESS.build({
    $1ph: Dimensions.get('window').height / 100, // 1 percent of the window height
    $1pw: Dimensions.get('window').width / 100, // 1 percent of the window width
});
```

You need to calculate this when the device loads and you can then use it throughout the app with:

```js
// Import react-native-extended-stylesheets
import ESS from 'react-native-extended-stylesheets';

// the margin will now be 3% of the device height
<View style={[styles.itemContainer, { padding: ESS.value('$1ph * 3') }]}>
  <Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Cut off Text????</Text>
</View>
```

Note that you will need to handle any orientation changes correctly to re-calculate the width and height.